# How can I create my own exception if an object parameter is null in C#

Tags: c#, exception

I am using the following code:

```
public static string ToJSONString(this object obj)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());

        ser.WriteObject(stream, obj);

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
    }
}
```

But when the object is null I get the following:

System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Is there a way I could catch this exception and return it to the calling program. Right now it gives me the above error and Visual Studio comes to a stop.

Comment: I would throw an `ArgumentNullException` in this case or - if you don't want an exception - return `null` (or `String.Empty`).

Comment: Well, it would be better if you'd throw `ArgumentNullException` - but it's still going to be an exception which indicates a bug, and shouldn't be caught... basically the caller shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: Try catch for that exception ands raise a custom exception. BUT it's the calling program that do this, not the callee.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I believe no program should ever catch NullReferenceException. The existence of a NullReferenceException indicates a bug. The bug should be fixed. Write code to avoid the NullReferenceException, not code to catch it.

Comment: As, what you have here, is an extension method, it won't even execute if the object it's being called on is a null reference. There's nothing you can do from within the method. All null reference checks/handling has to be done in the caller.

Comment: @ykb That is not true. You can definitely call an extension method on a null reference.

Comment: That's why I put in the BUT. I too would rather not make the call for a null reference. I'd view having to as a design flaw.

Comment: @ykb: `object obj1 = null; string json = obj1.ToJSONString();` wouldn't throw a `NullReferenceException`. An extension method is a  static method, you don't need an instance.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten, of course! My bad. Not sure how I could forget that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct way to handle your specific case would be

```
if (myObject != null)
{
     string json = myObject.ToJSONString(); 
     // other logic
}
else
{
     // handle the situation where myObject is null
}
```

Doing this, you're avoiding the exception to trigger.

Comment: Even after the edit, the assumption is now that the call can and should handle the exception. You could be right in this case, but if it were me I'd qualify my opening sentence, anything else is just swallowing